# Specific data from a dataframe based on date in another column

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

```
@app.callback(
    Output('stats', 'children'),
    Input('picker_main', 'date'))
def update_table(date_value):
    table = {}
    for query_id in queries_daily:
        df_temp = data_manager.data[query_id]
        df_temp.set_index('day')
        try:
            table[query_id] = df_temp[query_id].where(df_temp['day'] == datetime.strptime(date_value, "%Y-%m-%d").date())
            #table[query_id] = df_temp.loc["day", query_id].where(df_temp['day'] == temp)

            #table[query_id] = df_temp[df_temp["day"] == temp]
        except Exception as e:
            table[query_id] = 0
            print(e)
```

I'm trying to get a row from the dateframe and store it in a dictionary or another dateframe.

It's actually only about this bit:

```
table[query_id] = df_temp[query_id].where(df_temp['day'] == datetime.strptime(date_value, "%Y-%m-%d").date())
```

table --> empty dict

df_temp --> df with 2 columns - first with name in  variable "query_id" and second with date. From which I'm trying to get value stored in the column named with "query_id"  along with the "query_id" keyword.

I've been trying also converting date to string format and using dataframe instead of an empty dictionary

It doesn't return any data. I posted a longer piece of code at first as was wondering if maybe someone spot that I can do something in a better way

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need `query`

```
table = { query_id : data_manager.data[query_id]\
                                 .query(f'day == "{date_value}"')['day']
         for query_id in queries_daily }
```

Comment: thanks but it only gives back an dict of empty series

Comment: @Pat try changing `{date_value}` above with `{datetime.strptime(date_value, date_format).date()}`, where `date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"`

Comment: it hasn't changed anything, but thanks for trying!

Comment: @Pat next time post a [mcve] to make it easier to help you :)

Comment: will do, it's only about this line

table[query_id] = df_temp[query_id].where(df_temp['day'] == datetime.strptime(date_value, "%Y-%m-%d").date())